# Intellij Idea in Mac 10.14 doesn't see the ios simulator

Tags: ios, macos, flutter, intellij-idea, simulator

I am learning Flutter development, and I have problem, The ios simulator coming with Xcode works fine however and I did some apps before in ios simulator but suddenly when selecting from IntelliJ Idea to Open the ios Simulator,my app doesn't run in virtual ios simulator but it runs in android Simulator perfectly.

When I tried to select open ios simulator in the top tool bar in select option, doesn't change and it still I get NO DEVICES

It's not seeing the iphone XS Max 12.0 simulator running happily next to it.

Thanks for any help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvdS5.jpg)

Comment: Are there any errors/warnings in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...")?